# How to run botium-cli in headless mode using google chrome

Tags: automated-tests, chatbot

How do I run botium-cli + botium-webdriver-connector in headless mode using chrome browser?

The webpage doesn't work with phantomjs browser

---

edit: Florian answer works, im running jenkins on ubuntu, also need to add --no-sanbox and --disable-dev-shm-usage option

my final config

```
"WEBDRIVERIO_OPTIONS": {
    "desiredCapabilities": {
        "browserName": "chrome",
        "chromeOptions": {
            "args": [ "--headless", "--no-sandbox", "--disable--dev-shm-usage" ]
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a Botium sample available using Chrome in headless mode: https://github.com/codeforequity-at/botium-connector-webdriverio/blob/master/samples/botbuilderwebchat/

In botium.json, the webdriver options should be set something like this:

```
  "WEBDRIVERIO_OPTIONS": {
    "desiredCapabilities": {
      "browserName": "chrome",
      "chromeOptions": {
        "args": [ "--headless" ]
      }          
    }
  },
```

Comment: ah man, my bad, was looking only at dialogflow sample, ya this fixed the issue, another thing is, if the server is on linux running jenkins, need to add --no-sandbox and --disable-dev-shm-usage also. thanks!

Comment: Awesome. Botium just hands all those options over to WebdriverIO, which in turn hands most of them over to Selenium, so there is not much need for documenting it on Botium side ...